# Impose limitations on arc4random()?

Tags: ios, swift, arc4random

In **Swift**, I am using arc4random to generate a number between 0 and 568.

I need it impose limitations on this however. For example, the number can't be between 10 and 40. How are these "limitations" added?

Comment: By writing your own function that wraps `arc4random`, and does not pass values that need to be filtered out.

Comment: Also use `arc4random_uniform`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Can I just do an if statement after the arc4random_uniform?

Comment: While I learned something from the answers, it is probably faster, and more normal, to just modulus by the upper limit - offset. 10-40 = arc4random() % 30 + 10 type of deal. I'm unsure if your question was literally, the limit (thus the answers are correct) or "a way to limit the output", which is why this is in comment. Also technically, rand() % N usually needs 1 more added since 10 will give a 0-9 instead of desired 0-10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep trying until the condition is met:

```
func funnyRandom() -> UInt32 {
    var ran: UInt32 = 0
    do {
        ran = arc4random_uniform(568)
    } while (ran > 10 && ran < 40)
    return ran;
}
```

In Objective-C, it is the same method as in Swift:

```
- (int)funnyRandom {
    int ran;
    do {
        ran = arc4random_uniform(568);
    } while (ran > 10 && ran < 40);
    return ran;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without calling `arc4random_uniform` multiple times

```
func funnyRandom() -> UInt32 {
    var ran: UInt32 = 0

    //we have less values
    ran = arc4random_uniform(568 - 40 + 10)

    //skip the excluded range
    if (ran > 10) {
       ran += 40 - 10
    }
}
```

More generically:

```
func funnyRandom(max: UInt32, excludeRange: Range<UInt32>) -> UInt32 {
    var excludeRangeLength = excludeRange.endIndex - excludeRange.startIndex + 1

    var random: UInt32 =  arc4random_uniform(max - excludeRangeLength)

    if (random >= excludeRange.startIndex) {
        random += excludeRangeLength
    }

    return random
}

funnyRandom(568, excludeRange: 10...40)
```